# Stripe invoice for one time charge

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a one-time charge in Stripe, I have already added all my products to Stripe, and I'm creating an order and charge like this:

```
const order = await stripe.orders.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    currency: 'usd',
    items: [
        'sku_0001',
        'sku_0002',
    ],
    email: 'test@test.com',
});

const charge = await stripe.orders.pay(order.id, {
    customer: customer.id,
    email: 'test@test.com',
});
```

However, on the invoice send my Stripe, it only shows one item, with description: `Payment for order or_1GTmxxxxxxQjbLdncktm0`.

How can I have all the ordered items show up on the invoice, or at the very least, something a bit more descriptive. My customers have no idea what this order ID means, or what they have paid for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing a new integration, I'd advise against using Orders, since it is [deprecated](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/guide).

The best solution depends on what you're trying to do, beyond the invoice mechanics. One great option is to use [Checkout for one-time payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time) to charge your customers. It does not leverage the products directly, but you can use that same data on your server to [populate the line items](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#create-checkout-session).

Your other option is to [create the Invoice directly](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/create-invoice#with-code), by adding line items to your customer. When you do this, and choose to [send an email invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-collection_method), your customer will see a [hosted invoice page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/hosted) with all invoiced items included.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware the the Orders API was deprecated, I'll definitely have to change this. But with both solutions, it seems I need to manage the products myself, correct? As in, I can't leverage the products in the Stripe interface directly?

Comment: You can't use the `sku_xxx` ids alone to create the line items, but you can leverage the same data to drive your line items population if you wish.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I think I initially misunderstood how to use Stripe. I've been able to manually create invoices now, which is great. I believe now I can just use the API to retrieve products and create line items that way.

Comment: Warning!!!   Using the checkout method, you will not be able to generate INVOICES,  only receipts. It's very strange that Stripe doesn't give that option. It's obvious that some customers want their invoices, not receipts...

Comment: Phillip: you're right that you cannot create invoices for one-time payments via Checkout, but you can use one-time Invoices and leverage the Hosted Invoice payment page for a similar customer experience: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/hosted